# Preveiw app - inability to select and execute more than 1 sql statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Started using the 'Preview App' late last week.
In the classic UI, we can highlight multiple rows and execute them all, like this for example...

`update table.blah set updated_ts = current_timestamp()::timestamp_ntz, value = 1 where account_id = 5;`

`update table.blah set updated_ts = current_timestamp()::timestamp_ntz, value = 1 where account_id = 6;`

In the new app.snowflake UI, we get the error...

`000006 (0A000): Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead.`

This is a major annoyance. Is this something that is planned to be changed in a future release?
Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the current limitations of the new UI for Snowflake.  Remember, it is only in Preview.  You will see more and more functionality from the old interface be moved into the new interface over time.  I am sure this is one of them.